# Remove duplicated rows based on two columns (in both directions) and retain only one

Tags: linux, awk

I'd like to remove duplicated rows from a tab delimited file that look like this:

```
 arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A4HWYP   arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.BWH72M
 arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A4HWYP   arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.PK5V4W
 arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.BWH72M   arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A4HWYP
 arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.D7QF3J   arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A6ZB5M
 arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A6ZB5M   arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.D7QF3J
```

based on columns 1 and 2 to get output file having one direction rows that look like this :

```
 arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A4HWYP   arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.BWH72M
 arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A4HWYP   arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.PK5V4W
 arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.D7QF3J   arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A6ZB5M
```

I am trying the code

```
awk -F'\t' '!x[$2];{x[$1]++}' input.txt > out.txt
```

But its not giving the desired output instead its simply removing the last line of the original file.
Is there any way of doing this using awk and/or sort?

Comment: If that is your expected output, your sample script seems to produce the right result.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
       !(($1 FS $2 in x) || ($2 FS $1 in x));
       {x[$1 FS $2]}' ip.txt
arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A4HWYP    arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.BWH72M
arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A4HWYP    arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.PK5V4W
arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.D7QF3J    arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A6ZB5M
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` set input and output field separator as tab character
- `{x[$1 FS $2]}` use first and second field separated by tab as key
- `$1 FS $2 in x` and `$2 FS $1 in x` checks if the first and second fields exist as key in any order

You can also simplify this to:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} !(($0 in x) || ($2 FS $1 in x)); {x[$0]}'
```

or (just realized that OFS isn't needed)

```
awk -F'\t' '!(($0 in x) || ($2 FS $1 in x)); {x[$0]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '!a[($1<$2?$1:$2),($1<$2?$2:$1)]++' file
```

Output:

```
arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A4HWYP        arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.BWH72M
arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A4HWYP        arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.PK5V4W
arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.D7QF3J        arahy.Tifrunner.gnm1.ann1.A6ZB5M
```

In case the columns have space in them, you should use `awk -F"\t"`¸

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an awk expert, so here's a solution in Bash, if you are interested:

```
declare -A db
while read line; do
  index="$(sed 's,[[:space:]]\+,\n,g' <<<"$line" | sort)"
  [ -z "${db[$index]}" ] && echo "$line"
  db[$index]=1
done < input.txt > out.txt
```

The trick here is to create an index that doesn't care about the order of values in the record, which I do by just converting each record to a set of lines, using `sed`, then running it through `sort`. Ideally `sort` would allow us to sort "words", but AFAIK it doesn't.